# Displaying different favicon when opening images in browser window

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site that simply opens images in a browser with no page code:

```
www.mysite.com/images/pic.jpg
```

I want to add a different favicon when the pictures are opened in the browser window.

I tried putting the following inside the /images folder but no luck:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$ /images/favicon2.ico
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As a workaround, you might try putting the images in a different subdomain, like images.mysite.com/pic.jpg. That way the browser should request the images.mysite.com/favicon.ico as favicon when loading an image.

Answer (score 1):

The browser always checks for `favicon.ico` in the root.

The only way of telling the browser to use another file is by putting `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/otherfavicon.ico">` inside html. So this will only work for html documents.

So when a picture is opened `favicon.ico` is shown, but when a webpage is opened `otherfavicon.ico` is shown.

Comment: Thanks Gerben. Essentially you cannot change the favicon based on what directory you're in through htaccess?